# How to create Editable forms in XPS document (e.g. PDF forms with Textbox controls)?

Tags: .net-3.5, xpsdocument

**I want to create a Editable form having TextBox control, the form should be able to submit to a web  service, which will then parse the document. Is this possible with XPS document?**

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into the same question.  I just browsed through the XPS spec, and it appears that XPS is focused only on representing static content.  I don't see any provision to represent things like edit controls.  Microsoft has made it simple to go from XAML UI markup to XPS by "flattening" the XAML UI, so I think they are expecting interactive UI to be defined in XAML and printable page layout info to be XPS.  This does seem to leave a hole in the middle: forms content that is essentially "static" in layout, but includes user input fields.
-Roy, Satori Labs